# Getting the type of a template template parameter with using

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have the following piece of code which does not compile -> http://ideone.com/bL9DF1.

The problem is that I want to get the template template parameter out of a type. What I have is `using S = A<int, std::vector>` and I want to get back that I used `std::vector` in making S and to use it somewhere else.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, template<class...> class Container>
struct A
{
  using Ttype = T;
  using ContainerType = Container;

  Container<T> s;
};

int main()
{
  using S = A<int, std::vector>;

  S::ContainerType<double> y;
  y.push_back(2);

  return 0;
}
```

I don't know if there is even a way of doing what I want. Without the template parameters added `std::vector` is not a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `ContainerType` as an [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), since `Container` is a template itself.

```
template<typename... X>
using ContainerType = Container<X...>;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LPILGvyahakdD6zu)

Comment: While the actual example works, for my real problem it required me to use `template` in the middle. So, something like this `S::template ContainerType<double> y;` I don't know why.

Comment: @Mochan In your real code what is `S`? And what's your compiler?